# Translated page does not show new paragraphs(components) that are added to the original language node (Drupal 8 core translation module)

Tags: 8

I've translated pages with Drupal's translation module. The issue that I'm having is that if you add new paragraphs(components) to the original language node, the translated page does not inherit those new paragraphs. Is that feature available? Thanks!

Comment: If you add a new paragraph of text to your default language, you’ll need to translate that text and add it to your other translations. There is no auto translation

Comment: @Prestosaurus thanks for checking it out, but what I meant by content was paragraphs(components).

Comment: Have you gone to the Content types "manage fields" form and clicked on Translate? example link: `/admin/structure/types/manage/page/fields/node.page.field_name/translate`. You basically just need to give the translation a new label like "my Content Type - es". Use the dropdown by the "edit" link by the field in question and create a translation of the field

Comment: I was having this issue because I had accidentally translated the paragraph field on the parent entity, but thanks! https://www.drupal.org/node/2735121